# define tax rule based on cart amount

Tags: cart, shipping, tax

I need to set a 10% sales tax if total cart amount is $1000 and above. This is because we are shipping item outside from Australia, therefore there is a tax charges for that case.

Is it possible to set tax rule based on cart amount from admin panel? I'm not sure if there is any way to set this rule?. If it's not possible, any programmatic way to do that? Thanks.